# Creating a document and adding to set in same route

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have the following route:

```
app.post('/accounts', (req, res) => {
  obj = new ObjectID()

  var account = new Account({
    name: req.body.name,
    _owner: req.body._owner
  }
  )

  return account.save()

    .then((doc) => {
      Account.update(
        {
          "_id": account._id
        },
        {
          $addToSet: {
            subscriptions: obj
          }
        }
      )
    })
    .then((doc) => {
      res.send(doc)
    }
  )
});
```

I am trying to create a document and then update a field in it (array) with a created objectID. When I call this route the new document is created however the new objectID is not being added to the subscription set.

Here is my model:

```
var Account = mongoose.model('Account', {
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 1,
    trim: true
  },
  _owner: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true
  },
  subscriptions: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true
  }]
module.exports = {
  Account
};
```

Comment: New _id will be in the doc object returned after account.save

Comment: The problem is not getting the _id - I have the id and am passing it on to the update however the update is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you have found the id and subscriptions is array then

```
    app.post('/accounts', (req, res) => {
      obj = new ObjectID()

      var account = new Account({
        name: req.body.name,
        _owner: req.body._owner
      });

      return account.save()
      .then((doc) => {
          return Account.update(           //return was missing which was causing the issue because of promise chain
            {
              "_id": account._id
            },
            {
              $addToSet: {
                subscriptions: obj
              }
            }
          )
        }).then((doc) => {
          res.send(doc)
        }
      )
    });
```

Comment: $push wiill add the value if it exists or not. According to docs AddToSet should also add to an array - but only if the value doesn't exist: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/

Comment: no it will not check if it exists but one thing you can do is check my updated answer

Comment: console.log is showing the correct _id from the document creation.

Comment: model added to original question

Comment: i dont think required : true should be there in subscription

Comment: Even removing required doesn't solve this. The account document is being created correctly. The issue is updating it after its been created within the same route as its creation.

Comment: got the issue. add return before Account.update e.g. return Account.update

Comment: That seems to have worked! Can you explain why that would work but not the way I had?

Comment: when you are in promises then to trigger the next promise in the chain return should be written before any statement.